# You may specify either a ''value'' attribute or a body for the column component, but not both

Tags: visualforce

what is causing this error?

```
<apex:page controller="wrapper_test_controller"  > 
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >

                 <strong>   Welcome  {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}!
                    <apex:outputLabel style="float:right" > Date: {!MONTH(TODAY())}/ {!DAY(TODAY())}/ {!YEAR(TODAY())} </apex:outputLabel>
                 </strong>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
         <apex:outputText >Select Student:</apex:outputText>
                <apex:selectList size="1">

                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stud}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
         <apex:pageblocktable value="{!schedules}" var="schedule">
          <apex:column headerValue="Teacher"  id="teacher" value=" {!schedule.obj1.name}, {!schedule.obj1.First_Name__c}" />
          <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!schedule.obj1.Subject__c}"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Room Assignment" value="{!schedule.obj1.Room_Assignment__c}"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Time" id="time1"  Value="{!schedule.obj2.time__c}">
          <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1">
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00 AM" itemLabel="9:00 AM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00 AM" itemLabel="10:00 AM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00 AM" itemLabel="11:00 AM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00 PM" itemLabel="1:00 PM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00 PM" itemLabel="2:00 PM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00 PM" itemLabel="3:00 PM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00 PM" itemLabel="4:00 PM"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="5:00 PM" itemLabel="5:00 PM"/>
          </apex:selectList>  
          <apex:pagemessages />
          </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Check Time" >
              <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!schedule.obj1.Id}"> 
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onclick"
                        action="{!check}"
                        reRender="ResultPanel">
              <apex:param id="teacherid" name="teacherId" value="{!schedule.obj1.Id}"
                    assignTo="{!selectedTid}"/>
              <apex:param id="schedTime" name="schedTime" value="{!schedule.obj2.time__c}"
                    assignTo="{!selectedTime}"/>
        </apex:actionSupport>
               </apex:inputCheckbox>
             </apex:column>

          </apex:pageblocktable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >


        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         <br/>       
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: as far as I get it -- instead of this two lines:
`<apex:column headerValue="Time" id="time1"   Value="{!schedule.obj2.time__c}" **><apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1">` you should make  this :
`<apex:column headerValue="Time" id="time1" ><apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1"  Value="{!schedule.obj2.time__c}" >`

Comment: Please put more effort into removing irrelevant markup. The error message itself should lead you straight to which `column` tag to look at, if not the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 4th column **time1** in the pageBlockTable is having both the value attribute bound to a field and also has a selectList inside it.

```
   <apex:column headerValue="Time" id="time1"  Value="{!schedule.obj2.time__c}">
      <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1">
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00 AM" itemLabel="9:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00 AM" itemLabel="10:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00 AM" itemLabel="11:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00 PM" itemLabel="1:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00 PM" itemLabel="2:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00 PM" itemLabel="3:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00 PM" itemLabel="4:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="5:00 PM" itemLabel="5:00 PM"/>
      </apex:selectList>  
     <apex:pagemessages />
    </apex:column>
```

You have to use either one of them not both. So if you remove either the value attribute or the selectList out of the column, it should work.